# Mono winforms failed to render Persian text

Tags: c#, mono, farsi

I'm trying to run a Persian application in mono. But the texts are disconnected and reversed.

I'm running this app on Ubuntu 19.04 and I also tried running it on a Raspberry pi (Raspbian) but no deference.

I also tried setting LANG environment variable to fa_IR.utf-8 but again no deference.

I also set the RightToLeft property of the form to yes but again no deference.

This is the output of `mono --version`

```
Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.1.3 (tarball Tue Apr  9 16:16:30 UTC 2019)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          yes(600)
    Suspend:       preemptive
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

The app Looks Like this

[image: a]

Comment: Have you set the `RightToLeft` property of your form(s) to `RightToLeft.Yes`? Well, without knowing your code it is hard to tell what's wrong with your program (or perhaps Mono)...

Comment: Uh... i guess StackOverflow is the wrong place for your question then. StackOverflow is for programming questions, not for questions how to use/setup/configure/tweak some software or OS setting. https://superuser.com is probably a better place for your question...